# Why do we need Poincaré inequality to deduce the equivalence of the norms $\|\cdot\|_{H^1_0}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{H^1}$ on $H^1_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, open-map

In my functional analysis course, my teacher told us that if $\Omega$ is bounded, the two following norms
$$u \mapsto \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = \|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)} \quad \text{and} \quad u \mapsto \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$$
are equivalent on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ thanks to Poincaré inequality. However, the other day I was reading a corollary of the *open mapping theorem* that states the following:

> Let $E, F$ be two Banach spaces and $T$ be linear, continuous and bijective from $E$ to $F$. Then $T^{-1}$ is continuous from $F$ to $E$.

From this we easily deduce that if $\|\cdot\|_1, \|\cdot\|_2$ are two norms on a Banach space $E$ such that there exists $C> 0$ with
$$\|x\|_1\le C \|x\|_2, \quad \forall x \in E,$$
then there exists $c > 0$ with
$$\|x\|_2\le c \|x\|_1, \quad \forall x \in E,$$
and the two norms are equivalent.

In our case, clearly
$$\|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)} \le \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)},$$
on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ whatever is $\Omega$ (no need to be bounded). Therefore, why do we need Poincaré inequality (and hence $\Omega$ bounded) to deduce the equivalence of the norms ? Isn't it  straightforward by the corollary above ?

Comment: It is important that $E$ is a Banach space in both norms for your corollary. So you'd have to prove that $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is complete with respect to $u\mapsto \lVert{\nabla u}\rVert_2$.

Comment: And it is not possible without $\Omega$ bounded?

Comment: In case $\Omega = \mathbb R^n$, $u \mapsto \|\nabla u\|_2$ is not even a norm on $H_0^1(\Omega) = H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Awesome question!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you would have to show that $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ with this new norm is a Banach space to apply this argument. Note however that it is not necessary that $\Omega$ is bounded for the Poincaré inequality to hold:

If $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and there exists some $j \in \{1,...,n\}$ and $M>0$ such that $\forall x \in \Omega$ we have $|x_j| \le M$ then there is some $C$ such that
$$\|u\|_{H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)} \le \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
for all $u \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ and thus the two norms are equivalent.

A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181105/poincar%C3%A9-inequality-direct-proof) - note that it is sufficient to prove the statement for the dense subset of smooth functions with compact support in $\Omega$.

If $\Omega$ is even bounded then by the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in $L^{2}(\Omega)$, which immediately gives equivalency of the two norms.